# What IPC methods can only be used for related processes?

Tags: linux, ipc

I had overlooked the following important issue, until I saw from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/027

> Two unrelated processes cannot use the arguments, the environment or stdin/stdout to communicate; some form of inter-process communication (IPC) is required.

Hope that I can get some clear idea of the big picture.

What IPC methods can only be used for related processes, but not for unrelated processes?

What IPC methods can be used without such limitation?

Mainly focus on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

the only 'related' processes are child processes. If process A forks process B then process A can connect the stdin and stdout of process B itself so it can talk to process b. This is how the 'system' call works.

Otherwise you have to do the things that he mentions (or shared memory or unix sockets)

Comment: Thanks. Among various IPC methods, what are notably not for unrelated processes?

Comment: parent => child stdin stdout connections

Comment: For example, what approaches in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches are not for unrelated processes, and what are for?

Comment: i have answered this several times. stdin stdout redirection works for related (parent child) processes only. All others work for anything